# inaccurate [ -L $location ] or [ -f $location ] when location="~/.bashrc"

Tags: variables, bash

It's my first time doing something with bash-programming. As a first example I'm trying to source my `.bashrc` from my `.bash_profile` - even when `~/.bashrc` is a symbolic link.

**.bash_profile**:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ] && ! [ -L ~/.bashrc ]
then
  # ~/.bashrc is a regular file. Source it!
  source ~/.bashrc
  echo "~/.bashrc found."
elif [ -L ~/.bashrc ]
then
  # ~/.bashrc is a symbolic link.

  # Recursivly follow symbolic links.
  location="~/.bashrc"
  while [ -L $location ]
  do
    # QUESTION: Control-Flow never reaches this point.

    # Follow link on macOS.
    location="$(readlink $path)"
  done

  # Check if final target is regular file. Source it!
  if [ -f $location ]
  then
    source $location
    echo "Symlink to .bashrc found."
  fi
else
  echo "No valid .bashrc found."
fi
```

This is what I expect my code to do:

- If `~/.bashrc` is not a symbolic link, but a regular file: *Source it.*
- Otherwise if `~/.bashrc` is a symbolic link:

  - Follow the symbolic link as long as the target keeps being a symbolic link.
  - If the final target is a regular file: *Source it*.
- Otherwise: *Give it up*.

As a test I created a symbolic link `~/.bashrc` to the original file `.dotfiles/.bashrc`. My code enters the `elif` as intended, but sadly never enters the body of the `while`-loop (as I would expect, since `~/.bashrc` is a symbolic link).

What is going on here? I think the variable assignment of `location` is wrong in some way.

Comment: In the future, try to break down your questions to only include the specific part of your code that's not doing what you want.  There's a lot here that has nothing to do with the actual issue; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. (If you weren't clear *where* the problem is, using `bash -x` to run something with each command logged to see where things first go wrong would help to narrow that).

Comment: BTW, also run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds -- right now, it's got a bunch of subtle bugs due to inadequate quoting that would become glaringly obvious if you ever had a home directory whose name included any characters in `IFS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
location="$(readlink $path)"
```

With:

```
location="$(readlink $location)"
```

Notes:

1. The variable `path` was never defined.  I believe that you intended to apply `readlink` to `location` instead
2. If you had GNU `readlink` (available on Linux, homebrew, etc), then the option `-f` could be used eliminating the need for a loop.
3. In general, shell variables should be referenced inside double-quotes unless one wants the shell to apply *word splitting*, *tilde expansion*, and *pathname expansion* to the value of the variable.

   For example, in the following line, we want *tilde expansion*.  So, `~/`  needs to be outside of quotes:

   ```
   location=~/.bashrc
   ```

   Once this is done, the parts of the script where `location` is referenced should be in double-quotes.  As one example:

   ```
   location="$(readlink "$location")"
   ```

   This becomes very important, for example, if file or path names contains spaces.

Comment: I think I can get `coreutils` via home-brew.

Comment: Why do I need the extra parentheses in the assignment of location?

Comment: @Herickson If you meant extra _quotes_, I just added a discussion of that.

Comment: I don't quite get it yet. Sorry. In the line `location="$(readlink "$location")"` `location` is outside of double-quotes right? So we get *tile expansion* and *wort splitting*. What would be a case were we **don't** want this behaviour? And what about `location=$(readlink $location)`?

Comment: @Herickson, first, you'd almost **never** want word-splitting there -- it means you could have more than one argument passed to `readlink`, but readlink's behavior only makes sense with the file as a single argument -- if you split a filename into two arguments, then the second argument is read as an optional extension to strip off the filename (for GNU's implementation); split it into more arguments than that, and `readlink` just fails outright.

Comment: @Herickson, and second, tilde expansion doesn't happen on unquoted expansion; it only happens during unquoted *literal parsing*. `foo='~/bar'; echo $foo` still has the literal `~` in its result.

Comment: @Herickson, ...what unquoted expansion *does* do besides word-splitting that you almost certainly don't want is glob expansion. Let's say you have a file named `* READ ME FIRST * .txt` -- you don't want those `*`s replaced with a list of the other files in the same directory when you try to run `readlink`, right?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the clarification. So this expansion doesn't happen with double-quotes right? I'm still wondering about this line: `location="$(readlink $location)"` to me it seems that `$location` already is in double quotes and nothing more is needed. To me it seems here: `location="$(readlink "$location")"` `location` is outside of double-quotes.

Comment: @Herickson, `$()` creates a new quoting context.

Comment: @Herickson, ...keep in mind what `$()` *does* -- it runs the command enclosed in a subshell, and substitutes everything written on that subshell's stdout into the outer command (either as a literal if the substitution was inside double-quotes, or subject to field-splitting and globbing otherwise). This means that what it encloses is *a separate command*, so it makes complete sense for that command to have its own definition as to what is and isn't quoted. Otherwise, `"$(echo hello world)"` would be looking for an executable with spaces in its name, something like `/usr/bin/echo\ hello\ world`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This totally makes sense! Thank you :)

Comment: At the risk of adding confusion, note that word splitting does *not* occur in a variable assignment even if quotes are absent.  That is `location=$FOO` is the same as `location="$FOO"`, and the double quotes don't change anything.  So you can safely write `location=$(readlink "$location")`, which may make it clearer that `$location` is *inside* double quotes rather than outside.

Answer (score 1):

This causes the problem:

```
location="~/.bashrc"
```

The tilde expansion doesn't happen in double quotes, and it doesn't happen in

```
[ -L $location ]
```

either.

So, don't use double quotes in the assignment, or use

```
location="$HOME/.bashrc"
```

or similar.